# Fourier coeficients as feature to classification model

Tags: time-series, classification, feature-selection, fourier-transform

I have to solve a timeseries multiclass classification problem. Some of these classes (Class 0, Class 1 and Class 4) have timeseries that are really similar to each other, as follows:

1. `Class 0`: Original timeseries;
2. `Class 1`: Generated based on `Class 0`. Multiply the whole `Class 0` timeseries by a **single** random factor between 0.1 and 0.9;
3. `Class 4`: Also generated based on `Class 0`. Is the `Class 0` timeseries multiplied by **different** random values between 0.1 and 0.9, at certain random interval times;

The problem is that my model does not achiev an acceptable `f1_score` for those classes. For example, consider the case where a `Class 1` timeseries was generated by a 0.8 or 0.9 factor, it is going to be really similar to the `Class 0` that originated it.

I have been advised to try to use Fourier coeficients as aditonal input/features to my model, both the magnitude and the phase. Consider that my timesries has `n = 24` points, then i am getting only the first `n/2 + 1 = 13` coeficients (because of symmetry)

Here is a picture of the magnitude and phase values of the `np.fft.fft` of 3 timeseries. One timeseries of class 0, one of 1 and one of 4.

[image]

As you can see, the phase of `Class 0` and `Class 1` are equal, and their magnitude are similar in shape but `Class 1` has a lower magnitude because of the random factor that was used to generate it.

The phase of `Class 4` is totally different from the phases of `Class 0` and `Class 1`.

So, looking at those graphics, those coeficients could be used to improve my model performance? If yes, what is the approach here? Should i just fed the `13` magnitude and `13` phase values as inputs to the model?

Comment: The rules are few in prediction, other than not violating the right side of the equation with the left side (i.e., don't use a target as a predictor with the exception of temporal lags). Given that, does your algorithm allow for hyperparameters as in a Bayesian model?

Comment: Are you generating these time series synthetically? If so, do you know that they are different enough to allow for accurate classifications?

Comment: @Dave Yes, they are synthetic. From the literature review of this specific problem, it is stated that theses classes are hard to classify because they are similar to each other. I have tried to use statistical features (like mean and variance of the timeseries) wich improved the model classification performance a bit. I am still trying to improve it, and came across these Fourier coeficients. But not really sure how to use it.

Comment: @MikeHunter Yes it does, i am working with Neural Networks (MLP, Convolutional Networks and LSTM).

Comment: If the time series are very similar to each other, then they *should* be hard to reliably distinguish from each other. In the simulation setting, you have a huge advantage over the empirical setting in that you know exactly how the time series differ. Sure, Fourier coefficients might be good features to extract that allow for improvements in ability to distinguish between categories, but if the signals are very similar (you know if this is the case in the simulation setting), nothing is going to allow you to get particularly outstanding performance.

Comment: @Dave I understand, thanks. Well, i am going to try to use those coefficients then. Have any advices in how to do it? Should i just pass all the `13` magnitude and `13` phase coefficients as aditional inputs to my model? Or there is any other better approach to this?